# tsql rowcount without executing update

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have got any TSQL UPDATE statement and I'd like to know the number of rows that would be affected or the @@ROWCOUNT before really executing the updates.

I think I could replace the UPDATE part of the query with a SELECT COUNT(1), but it seems to me there should be an easier way.
Is there an easier way?

If there is no easy solution in SQL, a solution in .NET/C# would be ok for me too; I'm using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand to execute the command anyway. 
I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Example:

```
create table T (
    A char(5),
    B int
)

insert into T values ('a', 1)
insert into T values ('A', 1) 
insert into T values ('B', 2)
insert into T values ('X', 1)
insert into T values ('D', 4)


-- I do not want to execute this query
--      update T set A = 'X' where B = 1
-- but I want ot get the @@ROWCOUNT of it, in this case
-- the wanted result would be 3.
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any particularly fast way to do this in SQL-Server, o wise Andrew.

Comment: @George Menoutis: It does not need to be fast.

Comment: @Vladislav: I hoped to get a better solution than those in the mentioned duplicate. But yes, it is in effect the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to use transactions:

```
begin transaction;
    declare @rc int;
    update T set A = 'X' where B = 1;

    set @rc = @@rowcount;
    . . .
commit;  -- or rollback
```

Just about any other method would have race conditions, if other threads might be updating the table.

However, I am suspicious that this solves a real problem.  I suspect that your *real* problem might have a better solution.  Perhaps you should ask another question explaining what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your script in a transaction and use `ROLLBACK` at the end to forgo saving your changes.

```
create table T (
    A char(5),
    B int
)

insert into T values ('a', 
insert into T values ('A', 1) 
insert into T values ('B', 2)
insert into T values ('X', 1)
insert into T values ('D', 4)

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    update T set A = 'X' where B = 1
    SELECT @@RowCount;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

When you are ready to save your changes, switch `ROLLBACK` to `COMMIT` and execute, or you can simply remove those lines.  You can also name your transactions.  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql

You could add a `SELECT * FROM T;` after the rest of the script to confirm that your object was not actually updated.

Comment: This still using select , as OP said he is trying to avoid that

Comment: I interpreted that as he didn't want to manually switch his `UPDATE` to `SELECT` in order to test.  In my response, I added a separate select in an uncommitted transaction.  In any case, my original answer was still wrong, because I omitted his commented out `UPDATE` and wrapped the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements, instead!